# In Devexpress xtraReport, how to remove hyperlink when export to pdf?

Tags: pdf, devexpress, xtrareport

I generate a report using xtraReport. There are some hyperlink in my report that created by setting XRControl.NavigateUrl.

When I export to xls, I can set the XlsExportOptions.ExportHyperlinks = false to disable these hyperlinks.

But when I try to export to pdf format, I could not find a similar thing to disable hyperlink in pdf.

How can I remove these hyperlinks in pdf?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest that you modify the report as it is shown in the [How to customize a report control's appearance only when exporting the report](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CodeCentral/ViewExample.aspx?exampleId=E1159) example.

Comment: But my hyperlinks are doing some javascript function. For example: XRTableCell.NavigateUrl = "javascript: dosomething();"; How can I deal with it?

Comment: Hmm, it seems that you wanted to disable the hyperlink during exporting... Could you please explain how the report should work in this case?

Comment: In my case, the report include a summary table(XRTable) at the bottom. Inside each table cell, it is a number. User can click the number to trigger a javascript function that will popup another dialog to show the detail information about this number. That is how it works in report. But after exporting to pdf, I just want to export to a plain table that have text number inside each cell. I don't want the hyperlink for each cell. Thanks